# How can foreach be used to create synonymous macros?

Tags: macros, pdftex, foreach, csname

I need many synonyms of many macros with key figure references?
How do I use the \foreach token as a \newcommand name?
I look to replace the ACTUAL output with the MOCKUP output
by generating and using the macros
\hello, \hola, and \bonjour (all having subscript 1) and
\world, \mundo, and \monde (all having subscript 2),
because the synonyms all refer to the same figure number.
If there is a simpler way to do this, please show it.
Spelling them all out by copying and editing is very tedious.

COMPILE:

```
bash$ for i in 1 2 3 4; do pdflatex MWE.tex ; done
```

SOURCE:

```
% filename: MWE.tex

\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}{\bf\LARGE MWE}\end{center}

\begin{figure}\tikz{\node at (0,0) {hello};}\caption{hello}\label{hello}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\tikz{\node at (0,0) {world};}\caption{world}\label{world}\end{figure}

GOAL: produce synonymous variant macros referencing a key figure.\\\\

EXPECT:\\
{\bf key:} $hello_1$ {\bf variants:} $hola_1$ $bonjour_1$\\
{\bf key:} $world_2$ {\bf variants:} $mundo_2$ $monde_2$\\

MOCKUP:\\
% NOTICE: this exercises the loops needed, but how do I generate named macros?
% PROBLEM: \foreach defines \key and \variant so \newcommand can't reuse them.
% FAILURE: \expandafter\newcommand\csname\variant\endcsname{$\variant~\ref{\key}}
\foreach\key/\variants in {hello/{hola,bonjour},world/{mundo,monde}}{
    {\bf key:} $\key_{\ref{\key}}$ {\bf variants:}
    \foreach\variant in \variants{$\variant_{\ref{\key}}$\;} \\
}

ACTUAL:\\
TODO
% TODO uncomment these next two lines when the \newcommands work correctly.
%key: \hello variants: \hola \bonjour
%key: \world variants: \mundo \monde
\end{document}
```

Comment: It might or might not be applicable for you but you may want to consider using e.g. Python or bash to automatically generate TeX code that does the task for you. That way at least you can understand what the code does and modify it if needed, less so if you use someone's code without understanding it.

Comment: Can you write out how you would manually do the task with `newcommand` in this example?

Comment: Thank you.  After posting this, I thought about automated production using Python.  If it cannot be done simply in TeX, doing it simply in Python is higher value than funky newcommands.

Answer (score 1):

TNX user202729.  A Python solution worked perfectly.

First the source code for IDEAS.py:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

(BS, OB, CB) = ("\\", "{", "}")
IDEAS = {
    "hello": {"hola", "bonjour"},
    "world": {"mundo", "monde"}
}

def newcommand(num, key, syn):
    print(
        BS      + "newcommand" +
        BS      + syn +
        OB + BS + "large " + syn +
        BS      + "raisebox{-2pt}" +
        OB + BS + "footnotesize" +
        BS      + "ref{" + key + "}" +
        CB + CB
    )

def synonyms(num, key):
    newcommand(num + 1, key, key)
    for syn in IDEAS[key]:
        newcommand(num + 1, key, syn)

for num, key in enumerate(IDEAS):
    synonyms(num, key)
```

Then commandline:

```
bash$ IDEAS.py > IDEAS.tex
```

Then latex:

```
\input{IDEAS}
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that each `\foreach`-iteration takes place within its own local scope.
So a definition performed in terms of `\newcommand` is restricted to the local scope which is opened up at the begin of the  `\foreach`-iteration and is closed at the end of the `\foreach`-iteration during which performing that definition takes place.
I suggest accumulating `\newcommand`-directives within a scratch-token-register where assignments are done globally and having the content of that register delivered when iteration is done. You need some `\expandafter`-trickery for having the `\foreach`-"variable"-macros expanded properly.

Probably the following code does what you desire:

```latex
% filename: MWE.tex

\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}

\newtoks\scratchtoks

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}{\bf\LARGE MWE}\end{center}

\begin{figure}\tikz{\node at (0,0) {hello};}\caption{hello}\label{hello}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\tikz{\node at (0,0) {world};}\caption{world}\label{world}\end{figure}

GOAL: produce synonymous variant macros referencing a key figure.\\\\

EXPECT:\\
{\bf key:} $hello_1$ {\bf variants:} $hola_1$ $bonjour_1$\\
{\bf key:} $world_2$ {\bf variants:} $mundo_2$ $monde_2$\\

MOCKUP:\\
% NOTICE: this exercises the loops needed, but how do I generate named macros?
% PROBLEM: \foreach defines \key and \variant so \newcommand can't reuse them.
% FAILURE: \expandafter\newcommand\csname\variant\endcsname{$\variant~\ref{\key}}
\global\scratchtoks{\global\scratchtoks{}}%
\foreach\key/\variants in {hello/{hola,bonjour},world/{mundo,monde}}{%
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \global\scratchtoks\expandafter{%
      \the\expandafter\scratchtoks
          \expandafter\newcommand
          \csname\key\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
                     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
                     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter$%
                     \expandafter\key
                     \expandafter_%
                     \expandafter{%
                     \expandafter\ref
                     \expandafter{\key}}$}%
    }%
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {\bf key:} $\key_{\ref{\key}}$ {\bf variants:}
    \foreach\variant in \variants{%
      %-------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \global\scratchtoks\expandafter{%
        \the\expandafter\scratchtoks
            \expandafter\newcommand
            \csname\variant\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
                       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
                       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter$%
                       \expandafter\variant
                       \expandafter_%
                       \expandafter{%
                       \expandafter\ref
                       \expandafter{\key}}$}%
      }%
      %-------------------------------------------------------------------------
      $\variant_{\ref{\key}}$\;%
    }\\
}%
\the\scratchtoks

ACTUAL:\\
% TODO uncomment these next two lines when the \newcommands work correctly.
{\bf key:} \hello { \bf variants:} \hola\; \bonjour\;\\
{\bf key:} \world { \bf variants:} \mundo\; \monde\;\\
%\show\hello
%\show\hola
%\show\bonjour
%\show\world
%\show\mundo
%\show\monde
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively instead of accumluating within a token-register you can use expl3's `\cs_new:cpx` for defining things globally:

```latex
% filename: MWE.tex

\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}{\bf\LARGE MWE}\end{center}

\begin{figure}\tikz{\node at (0,0) {hello};}\caption{hello}\label{hello}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\tikz{\node at (0,0) {world};}\caption{world}\label{world}\end{figure}

GOAL: produce synonymous variant macros referencing a key figure.\\\\

EXPECT:\\
{\bf key:} $hello_1$ {\bf variants:} $hola_1$ $bonjour_1$\\
{\bf key:} $world_2$ {\bf variants:} $mundo_2$ $monde_2$\\

MOCKUP:\\
% NOTICE: this exercises the loops needed, but how do I generate named macros?
% PROBLEM: \foreach defines \key and \variant so \newcommand can't reuse them.
% FAILURE: \expandafter\newcommand\csname\variant\endcsname{$\variant~\ref{\key}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\foreach\key/\variants in {hello/{hola,bonjour},world/{mundo,monde}}{
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \cs_new:cpx{\key}
               {\c_math_toggle_token\exp_not:o {\key}\c_math_subscript_token{\exp_not:N\ref{\exp_not:o {\key}}}\c_math_toggle_token}
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {\bf key:}~\c_math_toggle_token\key\c_math_subscript_token{\ref{\key}}\c_math_toggle_token~{\bf variants:}~
    \foreach\variant in \variants{
      %-------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \cs_new:cpx{\variant}
                 {\c_math_toggle_token\exp_not:o {\variant}\c_math_subscript_token{\exp_not:N\ref{\exp_not:o {\key}}}\c_math_toggle_token}
      %-------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \c_math_toggle_token\variant\c_math_subscript_token{\ref{\key}}\c_math_toggle_token\;
    }\\
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

ACTUAL:\\
% TODO uncomment these next two lines when the \newcommands work correctly.
{\bf key:} \hello { \bf variants:} \hola\; \bonjour\;\\
{\bf key:} \world { \bf variants:} \mundo\; \monde\;\\
%\show\hello
%\show\hola
%\show\bonjour
%\show\world
%\show\mundo
%\show\monde
\end{document}
```

[image]